# ping -R and traceroute mismatch

Tags: ping, networking

I am stuck at a very strange result after running the command `ping -R` in a unix environment. To be more specific, I am trying to follow the path to a server and back but there is quite a mismach between the results from running this command and the `traceroute` to the same server. Why is that? I am already familiar with the concept of `ping -R` command and have actually read the manual page very thoroughly, however, I had no luck in expldaining to myself why that could happen. Any suggestions would be much appreciated as I am really confused. Thanks

Comment: Is this consistently appearing discrepancy? Remember that the actual route may change between or even in the middle of your trace.

Comment: Asymmetric routing?

Comment: @AdamZalcman: yes it is very consistent and the number of hops is small (8) so everything should work as supposed (I think!)

Comment: @joeqwerty: Well it could be routed asymmetrically, however the forward route should look the same either by using ping -R or traceroute (or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 3):

Ping -r displays outgoing IP addresses, i.e. addresses when leaving the routers, while traceroute displays addresses when entering the routers.
If the 9-address limit of ping -r is sufficient to display all the addresses encountered in a round trip, you can see first the addresses opposite to you, then the addresses towards you.
With traceroute you only see the addresses towards you.